# a question about ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to  prove the following statement?

> "$\phi$ is a ring homomorphism from $a$ to $b$ , $\textbf{Im}(\phi)$ is not an ideal of $b$ if $\phi$ is not a surjective homomorphism."

Comment: What are your exact requirements for a ring homomorphism? (They differ from context to context and person to person, and if you don't have the "right" definition, then the statement isn't true.)

Comment: it is a problem in the class of commutative algebra,I think teacher suppose a and b are both commutative ring with identity 1.But there is  no requirements on the homomorphism.

Comment: @player1 What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Of course there are requirements on homomorphisms. You need things like $\phi(a+b) = \phi(a)+\phi(b)$, otherwise it's just a function. What is your exact list? (I didn't mean requirements for this specific problem, I meant in general: what does "ring homomorphism" mean to you?)

Comment: Hint (in certain cases): $\phi(1)$ is in the image of $\phi$.

Comment: phi(a+b)=phi(a)+phi(b),phi(ab)=phi(a)phi(b),phi(1)=phi(1)

Comment: thanks all,I think I get it now.

Comment: It might be easier to prove the contrapositive of your statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi : A \mapsto B$ be a ring homomorphism. Assume $\phi$ isn't surjective, then there's $b \in B \setminus \operatorname{Im}(A)$.

We have $1_B = \phi(1_A) \in \operatorname{Im}(A)$. If $\operatorname{Im}(A)$ were an ideal of $B$, we would hence have $1_B \cdot b = b \in \operatorname{Im}(A)$, a contradiction!